# Simple jQuery toggle() won't work

Tags: jquery, toggle

jQuery is linked, no spelling misteakes, syntax is correct? I bet it's something really stupid but I'm going crazy here. Any ideas?

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#toggle-1").click(function(){
    $("#box-info-1").toggle();
  });
});
```

html:

```
<div id="section-1">
    <p class="map-toggle" id="toggle-1">1</p>
    <div id="box-info-1">
        <div class="arrow-up"></div>
        <div class="info" id="info-1"></div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#section-1 {
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 300px;
margin-top: 60px;
}

#box-info-1 {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: your code is works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="section-1">
    <p class="map-toggle" id="toggle-1">1</p>
    <div id="box-info-1">
        <div class="arrow-up"></div>
        <div class="info" id="info-1"></div>
    </div>  
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#toggle-1").click(function(){
    $("#box-info-1").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
```

I ran this code and it was running fine when I clicked on the icon. Toggling it added the `style="display: none;"` to the `box-info-1` div.

Maybe you're meaning to do something else? Or Jquery isn't properly linked?

Comment: Sorry, just added the css in my post. Display: none is already there, I want it to toggle between show and hide! jQuery is properly linked, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Fixed, didn't have the jQuery script right below title